# I am using Async's Library Parallel method wrong? But how?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the [async library's parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) function, but I am running into a weird problem.  I loop through an array of objects to create an array of functions called people.  People gets passed into async's parallel method to execute in parallel.  However, when I take a look at the parameter "people" that actually get passed into the  "printFunction" it is wrong.  The people parameter is always the last object in my people array.

So in this example, the console log in printFunction would print

```
{ 'name' : 'jar jar binks' }
{ 'name' : 'jar jar binks' }
```

Code:

```
var people = [{ 'name' : 'obi wan kenobi'}, { 'name' : 'jar jar binks' }];

// Create an array of tasks to be processed.
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  tasks.push( function(callback) {
    setTimeout( makePrintFunction(people[i], callback), 200); 
  });
}

// Process those tasks.
async.parallel(tasks, function(err, stuff) {
  // ...do some stuff with the returned array here.
});
```

**Make Print Function:**

```
function makePrintFunction(people, next) {
  return validateAndTrackFlag(people, next);
}

function printFunction(people, next) {
  console.log(people);        // Always prints: { 'name' : 'jar jar binks' }
  next(null, true)
}
```

Obviously this is not the real code, I just changed the names and objects.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Since you're using an array, perhaps [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) or [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) make  more sense than using `async.parallel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an async problem, it's a closure problem.

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  (function (i){
    tasks.push( function(callback) {
      setTimeout( makePrintFunction(people[i], callback), 200); 
    });
  })(i)
}
```

Or this:

```
people.forEach (function (p){
  tasks.push( function(callback) {
    setTimeout( makePrintFunction(p, callback), 200); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with classical scoping issue. Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    tasks.push( function(callback) {
      setTimeout( makePrintFunction(people[i], callback), 200); 
    });
  })(i);
}
```

or even better

```
var create_scope = function(i) {
  tasks.push( function(callback) {
    setTimeout( makePrintFunction(people[i], callback), 200); 
  });
};
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  create_scope(i);
}
```

or the best:

```
people.forEach(function(person) {
  tasks.push( function(callback) {
    setTimeout( makePrintFunction(person, callback), 200); 
  });
});
```

This happens because `for` loop does not create a scope, i.e. when functions are fired `i` is the last index. Now functions do create scope, so inside anonymous function `i` is the expected value.

Comment: Or `people.forEach(function(person) { ... })`.

Comment: Oh dang you beat me :) (although the first argument of the callback to `forEach` will be the array item and not the index :)

Comment: Yeah, it was so obvious, that I didn't think that there might be a mistake. :)